# Handling large data through restapi

Tags: json, node.js, rest, http, content-type

I have a RestFul server that is suppuse to return a large json object more specifically an array of objects to browsers. For example 30,000 points will have a size of 6.5mb.

But I get this content mismatch error in browser when speed is slow. I feel it is because large data throught rest api breaks up something. Even in Postman sometimes it fails to render even though i see data of 6.5 mb received.

My Server is in NodeJS. and return content-type header is application/json.

**My Question is**

Would it make more sense if I return a .json file. Will the browser be able to handle. If yes, then I will download the file and make front end changes.

**Old URL** - http://my-rest-server/data

**Proposed Url** - http://my-rest-server/data.json

What would be content-type in the proposed url?

Comment: is pagination not an option?

Comment: 1.5mb is not very large. Please edit your question to include the server code that handles this request.

Comment: But over a slow connection it is large

Comment: @daniel pagination is an option. But the client wants all the data at once. I am kind of in a bad spot

Comment: @JordanRunning over slow connection it is large.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the server code that handles this request.

Comment: If pagination is an option, go for it. It's the way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Your client can't possibly expect to want all of the data at once but still, want their data fast data.

...but you might want to look into sending data in chunks and streams:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93